# Getting all instances of a column when the substr is greater than 1

Tags: mysql

Ok, I've got a unique identifier, and at one point, these got cloned, along with the rows going with them.

To keep those rows (some of which were legitimate), we took off the last 3 characters of a given id and gave it three new ones.

I want to grab all of the unique identifiers which are identified by a multiple of the truncated id - for example:

> ID 1:
>
> 123456789
>
> ID 2:
>
> 123456888

I'd like to take a look at the substring (which in this case would be 123456), and grab both values that contain it.

This is what I currently have:

```
select substr(uuid, 1, 33) as substring, uuid 
from node 
where uuid like concat('', substr(uuid, 1, 33), '%') 
and count(substr(uuid, 1, 33)) > 1
```

However I get "invalid use of the group function". Should I be using `group by` and `having`? How would I use them appropriately in this context?

My goal is to grab every item in the uuid field that has a given substring of the uuid field more than one time.

So any uuid that contains a given string that another uuid does (that is, there is a repeating substring in the uuid) should be pulled and displayed.

This query, for example, gives me the substrings that have the uuids that I want, but it doesn't give me the uuids themselves:

```
select substr(uuid, 1, 33) as substring, uuid from node where uuid like concat('', substr(uuid, 1, 33), '%') group by substring having count(substring) > 1
```

I want the uuids associated with the substring, as such:

substring:

0e3c1fef-3958-436b-8e2b-0c6f7b7be

uuids:

0e3c1fef-3958-436b-8e2b-0c6f7b7be212

0e3c1fef-3958-436b-8e2b-0c6f7b7be075

0e3c1fef-3958-436b-8e2b-0c6f7b7be981

**So basically all of the uuids associated with multiple instances of a substring.**

The count for this particular substring would be 3.

Comment: `count` is an aggregate function, do you mean `length`?

Comment: `uuid LIKE CONCAT('%', substr(uuid, 1, 33), '%')` is always true. A column is always like itself.

Comment: Well then I probably only want % on the right end. But my larger question still remains.

Comment: You can't refer to column aliases in the `WHERE` clause of a query. Either repeat the expression, or use it in `HAVING`.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work still.

Comment: Could you give a better example. Please show more rows of the input table, and which rows should be included and excluded in the results.

Comment: It's still not clear what you're trying to do. You can't use `COUNT` in the `WHERE` clause, since it's an aggregate function.

Comment: `uid LIKE CONCAT(SUBSTR(uid, 1, 33), '%')` is also always true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate functions can't be used in the `WHERE` clause, they can only be used in `HAVING`.

```
SELECT uuid
FROM node
WHERE SUBSTR(uuid, 1, 33) IN (
    SELECT substr(uuid, 1, 33) as substring
    FROM node
    GROUP BY substring
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Another way to write it that might use indexes better is:

```
SELECT uuid
FROM node AS n
JOIN (SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTR(uuid, 1, 33), '%') AS pattern
      FROM node
      GROUP BY pattern
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) AS p
ON n.uuid LIKE p.pattern
```

Comment: This looks on first glance like it should work (though I am selecting uuid not uid), but the query is proceeding very slowly.

Comment: My first query probably can't make use of an index on `uuid`. Try the second query I just added.

Comment: It ran it's course before I saw the new query, so I have all of the rows I need it appears. I'll double check it and if it looks correct, I'll give you the answer.

Comment: Yep, it worked, and the second query was far faster than the first.